# Summing Over List of Lists Where Sublist Indices are Digits

Tags: java, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, multidimensional-array

The input is a really long 2D list.
Each sublist represents a number as 1 digit per index (i.e. [1, 4, 5] = 145)
Negative numbers are guaranteed to have the negative sign at the beginning (i.e. [-3, 4] is -34)

Normally, I would take each number, convert it to an integer and increment it to a variable.

How would I write code to sum all the numbers in this 2D array of lists without converting the numbers to integer form? (since it would cause integer overflow)

Here's some examples:

- [[1, 0], [-1, 0], [7]] => [7]
- [[5], [-1, 0]] => [-5]

Comment: You can calculate each digit value as the its value times a power of ten where that power is the length of the sublist minus one minus the position of the digit in the array. So for `[1, 4, 5]` the 1 is `1 * 10 ** (3 - 1 - 0)` or 100, and the 4 is `4 * 10 ** (3 - 1 - 1)` or 40. But if the numbers are still too large for an int, you will need to use a bignum or find pairs of values that cancel out (if you know there always will be) and remove them before you begin. But that is way too broad for a single SO question.

Comment: Are you using Java or Python?

Comment: Just had another thought. You could find the length of the longest list, and then create a list of all zeros of that length. Then, sum each digit at each position into this new list. If the numbers that make it too big all cancel each other out, you should end up with a list you can evaluate that won't be too large to fit in an int.

Comment: I'm using Python, and I can't use your first technique because each of the individual integers would overflow since it's a long list of long integers that are represented by a list.

Comment: I don't understand. Python has bignums. They shouldn't overflow. Have you actually tried it, or are you just expecting that they will? I just did `6 * 10**100` in Python 3 and it happily gave me the very big answer.